# Creating Schedule Task from xml using Python

Tags: python, xml, scheduled-tasks

I have an `.XML` file containing scheduled Task and I would like to add it to the task  scheduler via python. Does anyone know how I could do this, or where i could learn how to do this?

Comment: You need to use some xml parser. If data is "flat", you will be satisfied with xml.dom package. For "hierarchical" data xml.sax could be useful. It depends on existing code too.

Answer (score 0):

There are various techniques in doing this. The simplest way is:

```
os.system("SCHTASKS /Create /XML foo.xml /TN Name_Of_Task /F")
```